# Docker Image For UWP Application

Tags: docker, uwp

From the microsoft docs:

**Docker support is available for ASP.NET projects, ASP.NET Core projects, and .NET Core and .NET Framework console projects.**

I've been trying to put together a docker image that supports a UWP application, but struggling to put the build artificacts in the right locations.

Does anyone know if a windows supported Docker image for UWP is in the works?

Comment: My colleague has replied to you on MSDN, you can go and see.

Comment: Docker doesn't display Windows GUIs. Or what kind of UWP app are you referring to?

Comment: for windows mobile, its for the build process of that application